# Play application config "the combination of these two settings"

Tags: playframework

In play application conf `application.conf`, there is this little comment:

```
# The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  #config = "db"
  #default = "default"
```

I have no idea what it means - what does a "default JDBC pool" mean, and can I change the words ~ like, can config be "mouse"? Can default = "anything"?

And what are the implications if these things change?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsJDBC)

`config = "db"`

> The name of the configuration item from which to read database config.
>   So, if set to db, means that db.default is where the configuration for the
>   database named default is found.

`default = "default"`

> The name of the default database, used when no database name is explicitly specified.

**As an example:**

Let's your `application.conf` be like

```
db{
  config="db"
  default="default"
}
```

It states that all the `db` configurations like driver, url, username, password etc. will be in `db.default` for which db name is `default`.

If say
    db{
      config="customConfig"
      default="dbName" //db name is explicitly stated
    }

Now the configuration for db is not default, it's a custom configuration where you read values like

```
db.customConfig.url
db.customConfig.driver
```

And your dbName also changed to custom

You can read more from docs.

Comment: i don't understand - are you just posting the docs ? Could you instead add an example of some sort?

Comment: Actually quoted docs. As of your request, updated with example.